# Determining Thread Safety in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing

I am writing a multi threaded application and I am also trying to work out how to write suitable unit tests for it. I think that's probably another question on how best to do that.

One more question, I have a class like the below knowing its not thread safe and want to prove it in a unit test but cannot work out how to do it:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> MyList = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string Data)
    {
        MyList.Add(Data);  //This is not thread safe!!
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule you cannot use unit tests to **prove** that code is either thread-safe or not thread-safe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ummmm.....help!

Comment: Mostly you have to do this sort of verification by reasoning about the code. The kinds of test that Marc describes are very useful and give a  lot of benefit. But they do fall short of proving anything.

Comment: @David it is possible to prove (by example) that something is not thread safe; the problem is that not being able to prove it doesn't mean it **is** thread-safe

Comment: @MarcGravell How can you prove something is not thread-safe? All you can prove is that code is incorrect. What kind of test can you write for which you can provably demonstrate that the failure is due to lack of thread-safety as opposed to some other form of bug? Clearly I'm bidding for the prize of "pedant of the week" here......

Comment: @David well, you can write a test that illustrates that the scenario is repeatable and working when accessed by a single thread at a time (perhaps in parallel on unrelated objects if you want to get fancy), and repeatable and broken for multiple threads accessing the same object at the same time; which *suggests* threading as the mot likely issue.

Comment: @MarcGravell You can't even prove that a piece of code is repeatable. Just because you have run it millions of times and get the same answer, you can't be sure, just from unit testing, that you won't get a different answer next time round.

Comment: @David yes, I know what you are saying - but: if something works 1M times one way, and after changing only one thing (the threading) fails 1M times, we can expect that most likely  the thing we changed is hinting at the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Proving that something is thread safe is tricky - probably halting-problem hard. You can show that a race condition is easy to produce, or that it is hard to produce. But not producing a race condition doesn't mean it isn't there.

But: my usual approach here (if I have reason to think a bit of code that should be thread-safe, isn't) is to spin up a lot of threads waiting behind a single ManualResetEvent. The last thread to get to the gate (using interlocked to count) is responsible for opening the gate so that all the threads hit the system at the same time (and already exist). Then they do the work and check for sane exit conditions. Then I repeat this process a large number of times. This is usually sufficient to reproduce a suspected thread-race, and show that it moves from "obviously broken" to "not broken in an obvious way" (which is crucially different to "not broken").

Also note: most code does not have to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks but I write a lot of thread based code and am trying to get the dev team to adopt unit-testing/TDD so our stuff does have to be thread safe.

Comment: Marc, what you wrote sounds very interesting, but unfortunately it is not very clear. Would you like to describe your process in some more detail and perhaps add clarity to some points like 'the last thread to get to the gate (using interlocked to count)', and 'opening the gate'?

Comment: @Jon I have some examples in the protobuf-net test suite I can dig out later (not at a pc right now)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. Would really appreciate it

Comment: @Mike It seems quite clear what Marc means. You want to make sure that all threads are blocked on the event before you set the event. The event is the gate. Getting to the gate means waiting on the event. Opening the gate is setting the event. If you open the gate when all threads are waiting at the gate, then you increase the probability that all threads will stomp on the erroneously shared data or whatever it is that makes the code not thread safe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I get what is being said but maybe it would be helpful if we could see some code demonstrating this. People not that familiar with threading and blocking may learn by example.

Comment: @Jon I don't claim this is especially pretty (I have a very "utilitarian" approach) - but: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.unittest/Meta/ThreadRace.cs

Comment: @MarcGravell Wow! Thanks! I took one of the tests and tried it on the code in my question but it seemed to suggest all was well which is odd. I also wonder whether the Assert is in the wrong place. I have put the code here https://gist.github.com/1931579 If possible feel free to add comments to the code. Also doesn't a Thread.Join block other threads? If so isn't that defeating the purpose of the test?

Comment: @Jon the Join is just the co-ordinating thread waiting for all the *actual* tests to finish. I'll look at your example - 2 secs...

Comment: @Jon you aren't checking the results of the add ;p not every fail is an error. This fails pretty much instantly for me: http://pastie.org/3478743 (in my case, exception was the expected outcome of a fail). That said, I did also get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` during an add, so it *can* error. Most likely, the latter was when the collision happened at the same time as a buffer-resize

Comment: Isn't the Assert better out the 100 loop or I suppose it may not error first time around

Comment: @Jon either would be fine; I'm simply testing each iteration separately - would fail faster. But yes, the result would be the same if you left it to the end and then checked.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the help. Out of interest would it make any difference using NUnit.Assert rather than Debug.Assert

Comment: @Jon none whatsoever - simply: I happened to have a console exe in front of me, ready for hacking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8299/discussion-between-jon-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 11):

I frequently write unit tests to prove that some set of code is thread safe. Usually, I write these tests in response to a bug found in production. In this case, the purpose of the test is demonstrate that the bug is replicated (test fails), and that the new code fixes the threading problem (test passes), and then acts as a regression test for future releases.

Most of the tests thread safety tests I've written test a thread race condition, but some also test for thread deadlocks.

Proactively unit testing that code *is* thread safe is a little more tricky. Not because the unit test is more difficult to write, but because you have to do solid analysis to determine (guess, really,) what might be thread unsafe. If your analysis is correct, then you should be able to write a test that fails until you make the code thread safe.

When testing for a thread race condition, my tests almost always follow the same pattern: (this is pseudocode)

```
bool failed = false;
int iterations = 100;

// threads interact with some object - either 
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() {
   for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
     doSomething(); // call unsafe code
     // check that object is not out of synch due to other thread
     if (bad()) {
       failed = true;
     }
   }
}));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() {
   for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
     doSomething(); // call unsafe code
     // check that object is not out of synch due to other thread
     if (bad()) {
       failed = true;
     }
   }
}));

thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
Assert.IsFalse(failed, "code was thread safe");
```

Comment: How is doing a join going to test it properly because doesn't a join wait for the thread that is executing to finish before another one executes?

Comment: @Jon: Once "start()" is called on both thread1 and thread2, they begin executing. The join() just tells the main thread (running the unit test), to wait until both threads are done to check the result. thread1 and thread2 are the ones in a "race", and when they each call the thread unsafe code, after some number of iterations they will reliably put the tested code into a bad state. When the join() exits, the main thread can check to see whether the test succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where we found Thread Safety bugs. To fix it we had to prove it and then fix it. That quest brought me to this page but I could not find any real answer. As many of the above answers explained why. But never the less I found a possible way that might help others:

```
public static async Task<(bool IsSuccess, Exception Error)> RunTaskInParallel(Func<Task> task, int numberOfParallelExecutions = 2)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Exception error = null;
        int tasksCompletedCount = 0;
        var result = Parallel.For(0, numberOfParallelExecutions, GetParallelLoopOptions(cancellationTokenSource),
                      async index =>
                      {
                          try
                          {
                              await task();
                          }
                          catch (Exception ex)
                          {
                              error = ex;
                              cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                          }
                          finally
                          {
                              tasksCompletedCount++;
                          }

                      });

        int spinWaitCount = 0;
        int maxSpinWaitCount = 100;
        while (numberOfParallelExecutions > tasksCompletedCount && error is null && spinWaitCount < maxSpinWaitCount))
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            spinWaitCount++;
        }

        return (error == null, error);
    }
```

This is not the cleanest code nor our final result but the logic stays the same. This code proved our Thread Safety bug every time.

Here is how we used it:

```
int numberOfParallelExecutions = 2;
RunTaskInParallel(() => doSomeThingAsync(), numberOfParallelExecutions);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

Thread safety is not something you can reliably test because by its nature it is non-deterministic. You could try running the same operation a few hundred times in parallel on different threads and see if the results are consistent at the end. Not really great, but better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: MS Research had a runner once that would identify all collision points an cest them msotly using a CUSTOM THREAD SCHEDULER in C# ;) Was pulled (pending productization, so no available download anymore from MS resarch). The problem is that you need that type of tool to validate all possible combinations some may be terrifically hard to produce by some hundred runs as they only occur very rarely.

Comment: @TomTom Sounds interesting. It would be nice to see something like that in production.

Comment: @spencercw Agreed. I think there is a real need for this!

Comment: Yes, sadly it is processor intensive and - well, we will see whether this + pex/moles appears soonish in visual studio 2012 ;)

Answer (score 5):

I've given up with unit tests to try and detect threading problems. I just use a system load test with a full set of hardware, (if there is hardware - often with my jobs there is, uControllers on networks), and an unreasonably large number of automated clients running flat-out.  I leave it running for a week while I do other stuff.  At the end of the week I take the load off and check what's left. If it's still working, no objects have leaked and the memory has not noticeably increased, I ship it.

That's as much quality as I can afford :)